# Verb usage with page jumping/navigation

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

For describing an expect result in an audit report of testing (Action: Click on 'LOGO' at the top right of the page), which one of these is correct:
(Expect Result refers to 'It should'  )

> - Expect Result:  **Go** to the home page.
> - Expect Result: **Enter** the home page.
> - Expect Result: **Access** the home page.
> - Expect Result: **Jump to** the home page.
> - Expect Result: **Navigate to** the home page.

Or maybe i should use some other terms like **reach**, **get to**. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are other choices possible like "get to, reach"?

Comment: When you ask questions like these, it would be helpful to explain why you think each choice might be best. More context is always beneficial, and it's important to explain what you're thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the mentioned choices are already good enough. The choice can be better chosen according to the exact nature of the purpose of your application and your testing.

Assuming that this is a formal audit report for a web application testing, and we want to describe the "**Expected** Result" of the action "Click on 'LOGO' button", here are my possible choices (preferred first),

```
Expected Result: Go to the home page.
Expected Result: Go Back to the home page.
Expected Result: Navigate to the home page.
Expected Result: Jump to the home page.
Expected Result: Get Back to the home page.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using real expect result like

> The Home page is opened

Or in any cases you could use

> Should redirect to the Home page